# How to write unit tests if behavior is different on handsets and tablets?

Tags: android, unit-testing

How you guys write your unit tests for `Activities` which behave differently on handsets and tablets? On tablets there are several fragments, on handset it's only one. Do you write two separate suites of tests for each screen size or you do `if/else` things in your single test?

Answer (score 0):

You should never do an if/else in your Unit Test (see [Conditional Test Logic smell](http://xunitpatterns.com/Conditional%20Test%20Logic.html)). It makes your test hard to read and it doesn't make clear what your test is exactly testing.

I would try to minimize the differences between the screen sizes. If both would use a common application layer, you can write unit tests for the application layer and cover most of the code.

If you then factor the differences to separate classes you can create a paramaterized test for those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you meant by "behave differently", you might be able to use a "values-{specifier}" format to set variables to values (like Strings, or IDs) automatically based on the same criterion that change the behavior of the Activity. This would allow the same test code to behave differently without conditionals.

I think another, weirder option is to surround a block of asserts for on configuration in a try, and catch AssertionException and place the asserts for the other configuration in the catch block.